# Extract contents out of an XML file

Tags: bash

I have a directory with hundreds of "X-directories" like "X...". They all starts with an "X". In every X-directory exists a content.xml file with a list of zip files. I want to check for every X-directory and their content.xml if all zip files exists in the X-directory.

Example:

```
actual directory
  +- X0000132
       + content.xml
       + data1.zip
       + data2.zip
  +- X0000138
       + content.xml
       + data1.zip
       + data2.zip
       + data3.zip
       + data4.zip
       + data5.zip
  +- X0013198
       + content.xml
       + data1.zip
       + data2.zip
       + data3.zip
       + data4.zip
       + data5.zip
       + data6.zip
       + data7.zip
       + data8.zip
       + data9.zip
       + data10.zip
...
```

The content.xml looks like:

```
...
<name>data1.zip</name><name>data2.zip</name><name>data3.zip</name>  (all in one line)
...
```

How can I do this in a little Linux Script?

Many Thanks

Jens

Comment: Consider to use an XML parser like xmllint.

Answer (score 0):

use `find` to gather content.xml's and `xmllint` to gather filenames. afterwards loop over find's basepath concatenated with filenames.